# How can I use htaccess to not display the ID value in the URL?

Tags: .htaccess

My link:

```
href="https://example.com/news/<?php echo $id,$title ?>"
```

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/?$ news.php?post_id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

This gives some URL: `https://example.com/news/1sometitle`.

In this case, is it possible to create a URL in .htaccess without an id value, something like this:

`https://example.com/news/sometitle`

Thank you

My attempt :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/id/(.*)/title/(.*)/ news.php?post_id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Please write the question title in English as well. And go check https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: "_This gives some url_" fyi, rewriting an URL doesn't "give" that URL, it tells your webserver how to react when such URL is requested

Comment: You say you want URLs "_without an id value_", but your attempt explicitly adds an `/id/(.*)`? Do want ids in your URL or not?

Comment: _"My attempt :"_ - that `news/id/...` can not possibly match on `news/sometitle`, should be pretty obvious. And that you can not "extract" any numeric ID from an input URL that does not contain any in the first place, also.

Comment: I don't want id in url.
At the same time, I apologize for the clumsy question.
I want to extract id value from url

Comment: Removing the `id` value from the URL would mean that any database lookup that uses the GET variable `id` would fail so you would effectively only be searching by `title` rather than `title` and `id`

Comment: Is there any other way to hide the id value ?

Comment: You can remove it by using `href="https://example.com/news/<?php echo $title ?>"`, but you need to make sure that it works with `news.php?title=$1` without the ID.

Comment: How can I create a url so that the id value is not displayed in it?

Comment: @drvoredi If `news.php` requires an ID to check it against the database, you will still need the ID and cannot hide it. Unless you have another mechanism, such as using a slug, or something similar.

Comment: Do you know the context?

Comment: _"I don't want id in url. [...] I want to extract id value from url"_ - you can not "extract", what is not there in the first place. And if you actually mean _remove_ instead of extract - well then go and _do_ that, remove it from the URLs you are creating in your HTML output; and then modify your RewriteRule _and_ your script logic that selects the correct content, accordingly.